# Tab-Bar with Table-Views - like iTunes/Music app!

Tags: iphone, uitableview, view, tabbar

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of the Music App (the one that comes built-in to all our iPhones/iPods.) 
My goal is to have:

1) a Tab-Bar controller at the bottom, where every tab click loads a TableView.

2) Need to make sure that the Tab-Bar never disappears when these various table-views are loaded

3) the Table-Views must enable user to drill-down further and further into other table-views, sometimes 3 or 4 levels deep - but the tab-bar should never go away

4) One last thing: if possible, all the loaded Table-Views should NOT be Navigation Controllers, but regular UIViewControllers that then contain Tables (this is because it doesn't seem possible to resize tables when they're created as "UITableViewController"s, only when they're embedded into regular UIViewControllers, as-in, dragged and dropped out of the Objects Library onto an existing view.)

Anybody out there go some sort of tutorial or even code-template/engine type thing that they can share with us on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understand, you know that it is possible to use UINavigationControllers as UITabBarController's controllers. What is the reason then not to use the navigation controllers ?

That must be completely what you want to do: create tables in the code or link it as the outlets with Interface Builder as you can either use UIViewController or UITableViewController (which inherits from UIViewController) as root and popped to stack of NavController.

Assuming you use XCode 4 here is the link to [tutorial](http://blog.willwinder.com/2011/05/xcode4-uitabbarcontroller-with.html)

upd:

for the header and footer views it is always better to use UITableView object's **tableHeaderView** and **tableFooterView** properties. Then you do not need to calculate the margins and update the view layout manually as it comes automatically.

Regarding the navigation, it is a general practice to set the controller containing the table to be the table delegate itself and then to use the method

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

when you select one of the table cells, that method is called and you can create an instance of the next view controller, preconfigure it and then push to navigation stack. Back button comes automatically - and you are done. If you have the table in the next navigation controller, be careful while copy-pasting the methods from the previous-one, i.e. if you have wrang number of rows at

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

your application will crash.

Comment: I checked out the tutorial you referred me to-very helpful-thanks!   However, my main issue is in using TableViews in a Tab-Bar based app. First, if I create view-controllers and make them of type UITableView right off the bat, I can't seem to be able to resize them. For example: I can't have a Table reside UNDERNEATH a custom graphic-header ABOVE it. UITableViewController automatically fills the entire screen. Second,"drilling-down" Tables into other Tables - I can't seem to make that work without errors. Which viewController controls which view is very confusing to me. Any tutorial on that?

Comment: ok, I knew about the header/footer settings options we have programmatically, but I didn't think that affected the size of the table itself - meaning, the part containing the data cells. But I'll look into it again. As far as the drilling-down from table to table, yeah, it could be I'm setting the wrong delegates - I'll have to do some trials-and-errors I guess. Are you familiar with any tutorials out there that really spell out the code for this step-by-step, line-by-line?